# Diagnosing memory leak from Windows DLL accessed in Python with ctypes

Tags: python, dll, memory-leaks, ctypes, dllexport

I've written an abstraction layer in Python for a piece of commercial software that has an API used for accessing the database back end. The API is exposed via a Windows DLL, and my library is written in Python.

My Python package loads the necessary libraries provided by the application, initializes them, and creates a couple of Python APIs on top. There are low level functions that simply wrap the API, and make the functions callable from Python, as well as a higher level interface that makes interaction with the native API more efficient.

The problem I'm encountering is that when running a daemon that uses the library, it seems there is a memory leak. (Several hundred KB/s) I've used several Python memory profiling tools, as well as tested each function individually, and only one function seems to leak, yet no tool reports that memory has been lost during execution of that function.

On Linux, I would use Valgrind to figure out if the vendor's library was the culprit, but the application only runs on Windows. How can I diagnose whether the vendor is at fault, or if it's the way I'm accessing their library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a program in C without dynamic memory allocation to test the library. The leak is indeed in one of the functions I'm calling, not the Python program.

Comment: I ran into the same error as you did. What python memory profiling tool do you use?

Comment: If memory serves, I ended up writing a pure C program (without any dynamic memory allocation) to access the vendor's API and demonstrate the leak. Once I proved that the leak was in the vendor's library, I notified them of it, and wrote a workaround in my application using multiprocessing.